# Can't link to class with templates using Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I wrote a nice little array class in C++ that uses `void*` to save its entries.

Now, I want make it use templates. This is my new header:

```
template <typename T>
class SimpleArray
{
public:
    SimpleArray();
    ~SimpleArray();

    void SetEntry(int idx, T setEntry);
    T GetEntry(int idx);
    // and so on
protected:
    T *pData
    short iNumEntries;
}
```

The functions are implemented in a different file like this:

```
#include "SimpleArray.h"

template <typename T>
void SimpleArray<T>::SetEntry(int idx, T setEntry)
{
    // code here
}

template <typename T>
T SimpleArray<T>::GetEntry(int idx)
{
    // more code here
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I want to use it in some other code like this

```
SimpleArray<SomeType*> cache;
cache.SetEntry(0, someThing);
```

I get a linker error stating that there is an `unresolved external symbol`

> 2>Thing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall SimpleArray::SetEntry(int,class someThing *)" (?SetEntry@?$SimpleArray@PAUsHandle@@@@QAE_NHPAUsHandle@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Thing::Function(int)" (?DelEntry@Thing@@QAEXH@Z)

Man, I hate it that the linker does not even try to say anything intelligible.
Anyway, the real trouble is that I did something wrong here to upset the linker.

Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: By the way, I'd advise you to use `size_t` (or a `typedef` for it declared in your class) for indexes and for `iNumEntries` to avoid problems with big arrays. It may also be useful to provide an `operator[]` (both in const and non-const version) to make your class easier to use.

Comment: @Matteo: Operators and other functions part of `// and so on` ;-). Sizes are intentionally `short`, since we are working with really really tight memory constraints.

Comment: Uh, ok, I didn't know it was specifically intended for memory-tight environments :) . Still, you should be coherent and use either `short` or `int` both for `iNumEntries` and for indexes. Also, it may be worthwhile (if you plan to use such array for complex types) to pass the elements by reference.

Comment: @Matteo: Oh, that is true. I really should make indexes `short`, too. Thank you, Matteo!

Comment: No problem. :) By the way, if you are on embedded platforms and you want to optimize more these arrays (giving them C-style stack allocated array performances) have a look at `std::array`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put all the code in the header file. C++ does not effectively support separate compilation of templates.

Answer (score 3):

Place the template in the header. You can't separate C++ template definitions from their instantiations.

Comment: Actually, that is not quite true; you can separate them, **but** you have to explicitly instantiate the templates.

Comment: @Fritschy: Then how would you do that?

Comment: @Fritschy that's true, but people rarely do that. It's cumbersome.

Comment: @BastiBechtold keep the code as is, but add in the implementation file instantiations of the template. For example, add to the implementation file `template class SimpleArray<int>;` If you have free template functions you use then you need to instantiate them too. If you need any other instantiations then you'll need to repeat that for each. Hence: cumbersome. It's simpler to just move the definitions to the header. But be careful: only do that for inline and template functions! Any other function must be separate from the header so it doesn't violate the ODR.

Comment: In the .cpp of the teplate: `template class SimpleArray<double>;` In your case that is not a good idea, as you might want to use your class teplate with all sorts of different types ;). Please put your template implementation int the header. Explicit instantiation is rarely ever useful (e.g. You have a generic code of some sort and don't want the header to expose the implementation **and** there are only a couple of template parameters **and** you know them beforehand ;) - that is a mouthful...). I myself have seen it only twice in production code.